# What versions of Apache, PHP and MySql will Tasksel LAMPP stack install in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

I need to have PHP 5.3 and MySql 5.3 or an estable not bleeding edge version of both, how do I find what will Tasksel LAMPP stack install on my Ubuntu?

Comment: PHP 5.3 is not "stable" it is end of life. Don't use it for new projects, and migrate existing projects away from it ASAP. And there's no such thing as MySQL 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

For LAMP(Apache-MySQL-PHP) stack to an existing system:

> sudo tasksel install lamp-server

To see available (unistalled - u) and installed (i) tasks:

> tasksel --list-task

For complete options, see the tasksel manpage:

> man tasksel

OR

> tasksel --task-packages web-server

Answer (score 1):

You can list packages installed from tasksel with `tasksel --task-packages lamp-server`. Below is my result from ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
mysql-server-core-5.5
php5-mysql
mysql-client-core-5.5
mysql-server-5.5
libhtml-template-perl
ssl-cert
libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
mysql-client-5.5
libdbd-mysql-perl
libaio1
php5-common
libterm-readkey-perl
apache2-bin
libapr1
libaprutil1
libwrap0
libmysqlclient18
libaprutil1-ldap
php5-json
php5-readline
apache2-data
libapache2-mod-php5
libdbi-perl
apache2-mpm-prefork
apache2
mysql-server
php5-cli
tcpd
mysql-common
```

Since these packages are going to install via apt-get, you can check php5 version with `apt-cache show php5`. My result indicates it is php5.5. You may try [How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version), but download and compile from php.net is a better option to myself.